# Где взять базу прилагательных русского языка?

Tags: python, база-данных, поиск-данных

Нужна база прилагательных для своего проекта. Возможно вы знаете где можно найти такую или поможете мне как-нибудь еще.

Comment: *"или поможете мне как-нибудь еще"* - только если уточните как и в чем.

Answer (score 1):

http://dict.ruslang.ru как пример.
Вообще, если покопаться в поисковой выдаче, можно много чего найти.

Первая тысяча прилагательных http://dict.ruslang.ru/freq.php?act=show&dic=freq_adj

Answer (score 0):

возьми например орфографический словарик [http://ftp.ru.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libr/libreoffice-dictionaries/hunspell-ru_7.1.0~rc3-3_all.deb](http://ftp.ru.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libr/libreoffice-dictionaries/hunspell-ru_7.1.0%7Erc3-3_all.deb)

в hunspell не обозначена часть речи, но по суффиксу `/A` получишь большой список прилагательных и причастий.

```
...
красный/AES
краснуха/H
краснощекий/AS
краснощёкий/AS
краснозвездный/A
краснозвёздный/A
краснознаменный/A
краснознамённый/A
красноземный/A
краснозем/J
краснозёмный/A
краснозём/J
красноводский/A
красноватый/AS
...
обогреватель/K
обогревание/J
обогреваемый/A
обогревающийся/A
обогревающий/A
обогрев/J
обогретый/A
обогреться/BLMR
обогреть/BLMR
обоготворявший/A
обоготворять/BLPU
обоготворяемый/A
обоготворяющий/A
...
```